# Android Layout Animation won't work

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, layout, android-animation

I have a `LinearLayout` (`LayoutContentView`) which can contain one or two view (`SubView1` and `SubView2`) (they are either`TextView` or `ImageView`).
This `layout` is in another `LinearLayout` (`MyScreenLayout`).

I want to make an animation on `LayoutContentView` so it can move and show just a part of it in `MyScreenLayout`.

Both of these layouts have `setClipChildren(false);` so it can let it's children draw outside it-self.

Depending on different parameters, I can change the size of the content, and the size of the content I will show.

Basically, I expend from top to bottom to show the two subviews and unexpend for bottom to top to show only the second subview. Before I expend, I increase the size of the `LayoutContentView`, so it can show the two subviews, and after I unexpend, I decrease the size of the `LayoutContentView`, so it can only show the second subview, and it let space on the screen for other elements.

Here is my method for expending and un-expending `LayoutContentView` :

```
mLayoutContentView.clearAnimation();

float yFrom = 0.0F;
float yTo = 0.0F;
float xFrom = 0.0F;
float xTo = 0.0F;

if (expend) { // if we expend
    // I change the height of my LayoutContentView so it we can show it's two subviews
    final android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mLayoutContentView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = subView1H + subView2H;
    setLayoutParams(lp);
    invalidate(); 

    // we start the animation so it shows only the second subview
    yFrom = -subView1H;
    // and we animate from top to bottom until it shows the two subviews
    yTo = 0;
} else { // if we un-expend
    // we animate from bottom to top starting by showing the two subviews
    yFrom = 0;
    // and progressively hiding the first subview and showing only the second subview
    yTo = -subView1H;
}

Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(xFrom, xTo, yFrom, yTo);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (!expend) {
            // if we un expend at the end of the animation we can set the size of LayoutContentView to the size of the second subview again
            final android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mLayoutContentView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = subView2H;
            mLayoutContentView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
});

mLayoutContentView.startAnimation(anim);
```

The way I made my animation I need it to apply on `LayoutContentView`, the layout which contain two subview, and with `startAnimation()` it doesn't do the animation.
I tried to use a `LayoutAnimationController`, but instead of doing the animation on the `LayoutContentView`, it does it on each of its children...
I also tried to do the animation on each children myself, but I don't know why, the second subview isn't shown.

Each time I've tried to use `HierarchyViewer`, but it's does see the change made by the animation.

Does anyone know a solution or have faced the same problem and found a good solution ?

*EDIT* :
Well it seems that if you set a `background` color to your `TextView` and move them with animation, the `background` move but even if you have set the fill after parameter to your animation, the background moves back to it's original position or something like that, and therefore as I set a background color to both of my `SubView`s, somewhat one of the `SubView`'s background hide the background of the other...
And there also a problem if after the animation, one of the `SubView` is still outside the its layout, there is also a problem during the animation, so I add a limitation to what I intended to here too.

Comment: what is value of your subView1H..?

Comment: It depends, but for exemple I tested with these values :
subView1H = 70
subView2H = 20

knowing that these values are the height of SubView1 and SubView2